# how to retrieve required data Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hey Everyone I am new to learn j-query and i am sorry for my poor English.

here is my ajax call

```
// Get All Designaions on Department Change
             $("#departmentDropdownForBody").change(function (evt) {
                var departmentId = $("#departmentDropdownForBody").val();
                //Prevent the browser default
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDesignationFilteredByIds", "Designation")',
                data: { CompanyId: 0, BusinessUnitId: 0, DepartmentId: departmentId },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                traditional: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#desigTbody').html('');
                    var tRow = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        tRow += '<tr><td class="hide" id="depId">' + response[i].DepartmentId + '</td>'
                        tRow += '<tr><td class="hide" id="desId">' + response[i].DesignationId + '</td>'
                        tRow += '<tr><td>' + response[i].CompanyName + '</td>'
                        tRow += '<td>' + response[i].BusinessUnitName + '</td>'
                        tRow += '<td>' + response[i].DepartmentName + '</td>'
                        tRow += '<td>' + response[i].DesignationName + '</td>'
                        tRow += '<td><button type="button" id="editBtn" onclick="getDesignation(this.DepartmentId,this.DesignationId)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" ><span class="fa fa-edit" /></button></td></tr>';
                    };
                    $('#desigTbody').append(tRow);
                },
                error: function () { }
            });
        });
```

please read this ajax call. i want to pass two parameters on my button click that printing against each row.  please help.

Comment: Which two parameters? I can see you're passing `departmentId` right now, along with `companyId` and `businessUnitId` hard-coded to `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to persist arbitary data using cutsom `data-*` attributes which can be retrieved using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

```
tRow += '<td><button type="button" class="editBtn" data-departmentid="' + response[i].DepartmentId + '" data-designationid="' + response[i].DesignationId + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" ><span class="fa fa-edit" /></button></td></tr>';
```

And use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind event handler for dynamic elements

```
$('#desigTbody').on('click', '.editBtn', function () {
    var departmentid = $(this).data('departmentid');
    var designationid = $(this).data('designationid');
    getDesignation(departmentid, designationid);
});
```

Note: **Identifiers** in HTML must be unique.